# [C#]Как сделать анализатор и классификатор трафика?

Tags: c#, трафик

Хочу сделать анализатор трафика, но ничего не выходит, нашёл некоторые сурсы, попробовал запустить, но они не работают.

возможно это из-за того, что я выбрал неправильное устройство, но у меня не выводится информация ни об одном пакете. Может вы как-то поможете сделать анализатор трафика?
Суть его в том, что он должен отлавливать весь трафик, что есть на компе, а потом классифицировать его, т.е. распознавать, где идёт какой-либо запрос телеграма, ютуба, какой-либо соц.сети и тд. Помогите, пожалуйста

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PacketDotNet;
using SharpPcap;
using SharpPcap.WinPcap;

namespace Traff
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        CaptureDeviceList dList;
        ICaptureDevice device;
        Thread thread;
        static ICaptureDevice captureDevice;
        static int i = 0;
        static string s = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void capture()
        {
            try
            {
                CaptureDeviceList deviceList = CaptureDeviceList.Instance;
                // выбираем первое устройство в спсике (для примера)
                int z = 0;
                foreach(var dev in deviceList)
                {
                    //richTextBox1.AppendText(dev.Name);
                    //MessageBox.Show(dev.Name);
                }


                captureDevice = deviceList[2];
                // регистрируем событие, которое срабатывает, когда пришел новый пакет
                captureDevice.OnPacketArrival += new PacketArrivalEventHandler(Program_OnPacketArrival);
                // открываем в режиме promiscuous, поддерживается также нормальный режим
                captureDevice.Open(DeviceMode.Promiscuous, 1000);
                // начинаем захват пакетов
                captureDevice.StartCapture();
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                Thread.ResetAbort();
                captureDevice.Close();
                captureDevice.OnPacketArrival -= new PacketArrivalEventHandler(Program_OnPacketArrival);
                return;
            }
        }

        public void Program_OnPacketArrival(object sender, CaptureEventArgs e)
        {
            if (i < 2)
            {
                // парсинг всего пакета
                Packet packet = Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data);

                var ip = packet.Extract<PacketDotNet.IPPacket>();
                if (ip != null)
                {
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("Original IP packet: " + ip.ToString());
                    MessageBox.Show("Original IP packet: " + ip.ToString());

                }
                var tcp = packet.Extract<PacketDotNet.TcpPacket>();
                if (tcp != null)
                {
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("Original TCP packet: " + tcp.ToString());
                    MessageBox.Show("Original TCP packet: " + tcp.ToString());
                }
                richTextBox1.AppendText("------------------------------");
            }
            else
            {
                captureDevice.Close();
                return;
            }
            i++;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            capture();
        }


    }
}```
````

Comment: Есть же готовый софт для этого. WireShark например.

Comment: Не используйте `MessageBox` для вывода информации. Выводите хотя-бы в TextBox. `textBox.AppendText(text);`